# Add columns with information OSM by osm2po?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

I imported the europa.osm network within my spatial database using the osm2po tool. I use this with pgrouting.

How can I know the information provided by the tag address (city, country, etc) and not just the information that osm2po added by default?

I think I should change the osm2po.config file. But I have no idea how I should do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the few addr:* tags attached to streets, the current version might help. But you'll need Java to overwrite some standard behavior.
Implement your own WayTagResolver or extend the Default one.
There is a "meta"-attibute which can be populated withr custom data.
Nevertheless, GeoCoding is one of the next steps I'm going to implement.
One useful first step is the PgPolyRelWriter (OpenSource) from the downloadable "latest snapshot" Version 5.0.26. It provides another table of boundaries you can check against the given road network.

[image]